# Trouble Centring divs after floating divs

Tags: css

In Google Chrome I'm having trouble centring my footer and text in the "what" div after the floating divs. You can see the page at this [link](http://www.henrynorthen.com):

It looks fine in Internet Explorer, but in Google Chrome they aren't centred :(

Comment: Which browser are you having problems in?

Comment: Please specify the problem you have. E.g. after `ul#nav`, the `div#latest` does not show the text centered. I don't see the problem, for me it looks all ok.

Comment: View it in Google Chrome and you'll see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin:0;` for the paragraph inside the footer fixes the issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant for the #footer not the paragraph. Cheers

Comment: Same thing, didn't do anything